# ASP.NET MVC - absolute URL to content to be determines from outside controller or view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I have some content which is sitting in a path something like this:

> /Areas/MyUsefulApplication/Content/_awesome_template_bro/Images/MyImage.png

Is there a way get a fully qualified absolute URL to that path without being in a controller or view (where url helpers are readily available).

Answer (score 9):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static Uri GetBaseUrl(this UrlHelper url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(
            url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url,
            url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
        );
        var builder = new UriBuilder(uri) 
        { 
            Path = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath, 
            Query = null, 
            Fragment = null 
        };
        return builder.Uri;
    }

    public static string ContentAbsolute(this UrlHelper url, string contentPath)
    {
        return new Uri(GetBaseUrl(url), url.Content(contentPath)).AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

and then assuming you have an instance of UrlHelper:

```
string absoluteUrl = urlHelper.ContentAbsolute("~/Areas/MyUsefulApplication/Content/_awesome_template_bro/Images/MyImage.png");
```

If you need to do this in some other part of the code where you don't have access to an HttpContext and build an UrlHelper, well, you shouldn't as only parts of your code that have access to it should deal with urls. Other parts of your code shouldn't even know whan an url means.

Comment: But that's in a controller or view - basically in Asp.net MVC app... Isn't it?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, absolutely not. That could be anywhere where you have access to an HttpContext (pretty much everywhere) as you can build an instance of UrlHelper from it.

Comment: +1 You're right. Fair enough. But you could as well bypass the UrlHelper instance *limitation*. You could just create a static class and call its static methods for what it's worth.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, you don't have access to HttpContext inside a static class. For me `HttpContext.Current` is not exactly the kind of code I want to see in my applications, so I intentionally introduce this limitation so that developers are not tempted to use this class in places where they are not supposed to. Otherwise they will end up using it for example in the service layer and I wouldn't be happy :-)

Comment: Why don't you have access to it? All you'd have to check is whether you're in an Asp.net thread by checking `(HttpContext.Current != null)`. I don't see any reason why that's impossible in a static class... This will prevent your functionality from being called in non-web application types.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, in non-web applications this class shouldn't be used at all. Also I hate writing code that is not unit-testable. Also I want my code to be self explanatory. By just looking at the method signature the developer already knows where he can use it. Whereas if you remove this restriction he might say to himself: *what a cool method this is, let me use it*. Then he imports it in his WinForms application and it is only at runtime that he will realize what a mistake he did.

Comment: I welcome your decision I just wanted a bit of reasoning behind it. And I agree with you on this. The main question is of course where *outside controller/view* does OP want to use this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is of course:
**Where would you like to get the URL then if not in a controller or view?** What other places are there in an Asp.net MVC application?

If you're taking about other app tiers that aren't aware of the web UI front-end then that would be a bit tricky. These apps (assemblies) could have custom configuration where you could put web app path root and they could use that. but you'd have to change it for production.

**Or** add a System.Web reference to your *other* app and access current `HttpContext` as Darin showed you which is an even nicer solution.