# url of main folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have several instalation with different path.

fe.:

1. http://Somepath.xx/
2. http://Someotherpath.xy/Maincontent/

Problem is, how to dynamycly detect the path?

I found way how to do this for first case:

```
Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + (Request.Url.Port != 80 ? ":" + Request.Url.Port : "")
```

But how to do this for second, or general for more complex example... i don't know.

I need it in controller as same as in View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) method:

```
string root = Url.Content("~/");
```

The Url helper is available in both controllers and views.

Comment: But AbsoluteUrl don't return it with the "Maincontent" part

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7266678/29407 And then use the extension method like this: `string root = Url.ContentAbsolute("~/");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) functionality and see examples and informal explanation of its workings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Hope this helps.